# How to solve a certain recurrent matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, random-variables, recurrence-relations

I am trying to find the steady-state covariance of a vector that repeatedly undergoes a linear transformation with noise. Specifically, the following recurrent relation should hold:

$$cov(AX + \epsilon) = cov(X)$$

where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ is a constant matrix and $X$ and $\epsilon$ are independent random vectors; $\epsilon \sim \cal{N}(\bf{0}, \Sigma)$. Due to the independence, we can write:

$$ Acov(X)A^T + \Sigma = cov(X)$$

From this, is it possible to solve for $cov(X)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody's answered yet, but I found a solution:

Let $C := cov(X)$ and let $\odot$ mean elementwise multiplication.

This identity holds trivially:

$$\mathbf{v}^TC\mathbf{w} = \sum_{i, j} (\mathbf{vw}^T \odot C)_{ij} = \sum_{i,j} \mathbf{v}_i\mathbf{w}_jC_{ij}$$

Since each entry of $ACA^T$ takes this form, where **v** is the *i*th row and **w** is the *j*th row of $A^T$, we can make a system of $m^2$ equations to solve for each entry of $C$.

From the last equation in the question:

$$C_{ij} = \Sigma_{ij} + \sum_{k=1}^m \sum_{l=1}^m A_{ik}A_{jl}C_{kl}$$
$$\Sigma_{ij} = C_{ij} - \sum_{k=1}^m \sum_{l=1}^m A_{ik}A_{jl}C_{kl}$$

Let $r(i, j) := im + j$, $\mathbf{\sigma} \in \mathbb{R}^{m^2}$ where $\mathbf{\sigma}_{r(i, j)} = \Sigma_{ij}$, and $\mathbf{c} \in \mathbb{R}^{m^2}$ where $\mathbf{c}_{r(i, j)} = C_{ij}$. Then we can write:

$$\mathbf{\sigma} = D\mathbf{c}$$

The entries of $D$ are:

$$D_{r(i,j)r(k,l)} = \delta_{r(i,j)r(k,l)} - A_{ik}A_{jl}$$

Then we can solve for **c** and reformat it as a matrix.

(I actually implemented this in Python using numpy.linalg.tensorsolve, which allowed me to avoid reshaping the matrices into vectors and back again.)